# Ordenar List por por valores decrescentes

Tags: c#, lista

Tenho um objeto **Cromossomo**:

```
public List<int> Rotas { get; set; }
public int ValorFitness { get; set; }
```

E também tenho uma lista desse objeto `List<Cromossomo>`.

Gostaria de ordenar esta lista pela propriedade **ValorFitness**, em ordem decrescente.

Estou usando C#, WindowsForm, DotNet 4.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `.OrderByDescending`

Exemplo:

```
var listaOrdenada = cromossomos.OrderByDescending(e => e.ValorFitness);
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando *linq (Language Integrated Query)* e *Lambda*.

Um exemplo:

```
List<Cromossomo> comossomosOrdenados = cromossomos.OrderByDescending(c => c.ValorFitness);
```

Outro exemplo:

```
List<Cromossomo> comossomosOrdenados = (from c in cromossomos
        orderby c.ValorFitness descending
        select c).ToList();
```

**[Nesse link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)** tem alguns exemplos de Linq.

Comment: Esse exemplo de baixo é Lambda? Não seria Linq? Acho que os exemplos estão inversos D:

Comment: @FilipeOliveira Estarei ajustando, obrigado.